# Index mistake when using pandas read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, import

Whilst trying to import the popular [UCL bank marketing dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing) from a github endpoint I ran into some issues. The read statement is not taking the dataset of the 17 columns correctly. I checked the separator and the header but I am not sure how to correct the index.

```
# URL endoint
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ThamuMnyulwa/bankMarketing/main/bank-additional-full.csv'

column_names = ["age","job","marital","education","default","balance","housing","loan","contact","day","month"
 ,"duration","campaign","pdays","previous","poutcome", "y"]


raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(url, names=column_names,
                          na_values='?',sep=';'
                          , skipinitialspace=False, index_col=None)
```

Instead, it is giving me something like this:

[image]

How can I import the dataset ([link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ThamuMnyulwa/bankMarketing/main/bank-additional-full.csv)) correctly from the URL using  pandas `read_csv` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set the headers. It already comes with the headers in the CSV. The reason yours looks weird, is because you are missing 3 values in your headers list, which is why it's offset by 3.

Comment: Does this fix the indexing?

Comment: Yes, it should add an index before the first column. Just delete the `names=column_names,` out of the read_csv call

Comment: I see what you are saying @FishMonkey, thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax shows a consistent result:

```
raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(url, sep=";")
```